# How can I label a LogLog plot with the label on the graph/line?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

I want to label a graph as shown in the attached image. I want the label on the line and parallel to the line that I am labeling, as it is shown in the image. Could you help me, please?
Code:

```
LogLogPlot[{Exp[4]* x, Exp[10]*(x)}, {x, 1, 10^3}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use custom [`Arrowheads`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html) as the option setting for `PlotStyle` and post-process to replace `Line`s with `Arrow`s:

```
arrowheads = Arrowheads[{{.5, .5, 
  Graphics[Text[Framed[Style[#, 16], Background -> White, FrameStyle -> None]]]}}]& /@
     {"W", "BLAH"};

LogLogPlot[{Exp[4]*x, Exp[10]*(x)}, {x, 1, 10^3}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> arrowheads, FrameLabel -> {x, y}] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very clever hack using `Arrowheads` like this. Nice job.  It's not likely to get easier than this.

Comment: @kglr Thanks a lot.

Comment: Suppose, I need to label one line and no need to label the other line -  How do I need to modify this code?

Comment: @PoreyS, `PlotStyle -> {arrowheads[[1]], Arrowheads[{}]}` labels the first line only.

Comment: @kglr Thanks a lot.